# Update the column Date` with the date less than two months using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table MySQL 5.5.62 host version

| uID | Next_control | Next_control_2 | Date_alert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45265 | 2023-09-07 | 2023-07-07 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-10-16 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2019-04-19 | 2019-02-19 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2016-09-18 | 2016-07-18 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2014-11-23 | 2014-09-23 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2009-08-11 | 2009-06-11 | NULL |

I need to update the column `Date_alert` with the date less than two months compared to the column `Next_control` only for most recent row for `uID` 45265

I have tried

```
UPDATE `dotable` q JOIN
(SELECT uID, MAX(Next_control) dt FROM `dotable` GROUP BY uID) t
SET q.Date_alert = DATE_SUB( t.dt, INTERVAL 2 MONTH ) 
WHERE q.uID = t.uID;
```

But the column `Date_alert` it is also updated for older rows for `uID` 45265:

| uID | Next_control | Next_control_2 | Date_alert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45265 | 2023-09-07 | 2023-07-07 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-10-16 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2019-04-19 | 2019-02-19 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2016-09-18 | 2016-07-18 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2014-11-23 | 2014-09-23 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2009-08-11 | 2009-06-11 | 2023-07-07 |

**Expected Output**:

| uID | Next_control | Next_control_2 | Date_alert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45265 | 2023-09-07 | 2023-07-07 | 2023-07-07 |
| 45265 | 2022-12-16 | 2022-10-16 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2019-04-19 | 2019-02-19 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2016-09-18 | 2016-07-18 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2014-11-23 | 2014-09-23 | NULL |
| 45265 | 2009-08-11 | 2009-06-11 | NULL |

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet one more option is to add a condition in your `WHERE` clause, in which you check for the matching "*Next_control*" value.

```
UPDATE `dotable` q JOIN
(SELECT uID, MAX(Next_control) dt FROM `dotable` GROUP BY uID) t
SET q.Date_alert = DATE_SUB( t.dt, INTERVAL 2 MONTH ) 
WHERE q.uID = t.uID AND q.Next_control = t.dt;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyq9UeXea6vReMTwaMawW3/0).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to update the column Date_alert with the date less than two months compared to the column Next_control only for most recent row for uID 45265

```sql
UPDATE dotable
SET Date_alert = dt - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
WHERE uID = 45265
ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks for reply, uID 45265 it's any example... my table contains other codes uID